# How to copy and find the last 125 row?

Tags: excel, vba, data-migration

I have a task where I need to get the last 125 data from an excel workbook copied to another workbook. And I want the user to select from a file browser the excel file where the data has been stored. The data will always in the the range of C17:C2051, F17:F2051 and goes on...

At last I want to put two formula above these ranges.

There are the formulas:

```
=AVARAGE(INDEX(C17:C2051;MATCH(MAX(C17:C2051);C17:C2051;1)):INDEX(C17:C2051;MAX(1;MATCH(MAX(C17:C2051);C17:C2051;1)-124)))
=STDEV(INDEX(C17:C2051;MATCH(MAX(C17:C2051);C17:C2051;1)):INDEX(C17:C2051;MAX(1;MATCH(MAX(C17:C2051);C17:C2051;1)-124)))
```

I wrote some code but right now it's actually doing nothing.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

Dim FileToOpen As String
Dim File As Workbook

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Last8Rows As Range

LastRow = File.Range("D" & File.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Last8Rows = File.Range("C" & LastRow - 7)
Last8Rows.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: `GetOpenFilename` doesn't open the selected file - you need to use `Workbooks.Open` to do that.

Comment: And with it the user can select the file what he want? Or I need to add that?

Comment: You need to add something like `Set File = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)` then select a range on a specific *worksheet* in that file.

Comment: Wow I never thinked about that! Thank you so much!
And are you have any ideas how to give the parameters for last 125 rows in the ranges from this selected workbook? And how can I copy them? Sorry if I ask too many questions I'm a beginner and I googleing all day and I don't find my answers.

Comment: Are you always copying for the same worksheet in the selected file?  Which sheet?  Where are you copying the data to ?

Comment: No, it is changeing monthly. And I get the data from the workbook what is used before the new one. And I copy the data in the same range where I used it in last workbook.

Comment: There's not much in your answer to my questions which would be useful in writing code to automate the process...  If there's no specific logic/rules to follow then it's difficult to automate.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem I have find too, hard to find the logic there. I try to describe than it more precisely

Comment: So there's monthly being created a file without data. And I need to copy the data from the last workbook I used. There rows and the columns are in the same position as the last one. So there's a row in the range of C17:C2051, F17:F2051. And I need to copy into the same rows and columns the data as the last excel file.
At first I want the user to select the file. After it I need to get the range of C17:C2051, F17:F2051 and copy the last 125 data into the new workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```vb
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

    Const START_ROW As Long = 17
    Const NUM_ROWS As Long = 125
    
    Dim FileToOpen As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRows As Range
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
                                            Title:="Select file to import from")
    If FileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub 'no file selected
    
    Set wsDest = ActiveSheet             'pasting here; or specfy some other sheet...
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("data")       'or whatever sheet you need
    
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
    If LastRow < START_ROW Then LastRow = START_ROW
    
    FirstRow = IIf(LastRow - NUM_ROWS >= START_ROW, LastRow - NUM_ROWS, START_ROW) 'find first row
    
    'copy ranges
    ws.Range("C" & FirstRow & ":C" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "C")
    ws.Range("F" & FirstRow & ":F" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "F")

    'Add the formulas (note you need the US-format when using .Formula
    '   or you can use your local format with .FormulaLocal

    wb.Close False 'no save

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot! I'll reply if I finally figured it out or needs help! :)

Answer (score 0):

After all these days it's working finally. I modified some lines in the code and it's doing the job. Thanks again [@TimWilliams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743280/13268855)!

Here's my solution:

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

    Const START_ROW As Long = 17
    Const NUM_ROWS As Long = 124
    
    Dim FileToOpen As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRows As Range
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
                                            Title:="Select file to import from") 'no file selected
    
    Set wsDest = ActiveSheet             'pasting here; or specfy some other sheet...
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("SMI_650_Lxy")       'or whatever sheet you need
    
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
    If LastRow < START_ROW Then LastRow = START_ROW
    
    FirstRow = IIf(LastRow - NUM_ROWS >= START_ROW, LastRow - NUM_ROWS, START_ROW) 'find first row
    
    Debug.Print "FirstRow" & vbTab & FirstRow 'test
    Debug.Print "LastRow" & vbTab & LastRow
    Debug.Print "START_ROW" & vbTab & START_ROW
    
    'copy ranges
    ws.Range("C" & FirstRow & ":C" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "C")
    ws.Range("F" & FirstRow & ":F" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "F")
    ws.Range("M" & FirstRow & ":M" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "M") 'formula
    ws.Range("P" & FirstRow & ":P" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "P")
    ws.Range("S" & FirstRow & ":S" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "S")
    ws.Range("V" & FirstRow & ":V" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "V")
    ws.Range("Y" & FirstRow & ":Y" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "Y")
    ws.Range("AF" & FirstRow & ":AF" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "AF") 'formula
    ws.Range("AM" & FirstRow & ":AM" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "AM") 'formula
    ws.Range("AP" & FirstRow & ":AP" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "AP")
    ws.Range("AS" & FirstRow & ":AS" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "AS")
    ws.Range("AV" & FirstRow & ":AV" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "AV")
    ws.Range("AY" & FirstRow & ":AY" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "AY")
    ws.Range("BB" & FirstRow & ":BB" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "BB")
    ws.Range("BE" & FirstRow & ":BE" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "BE")
    ws.Range("BL" & FirstRow & ":BL" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "BL") 'formula
    ws.Range("BS" & FirstRow & ":BS" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "BS") 'formula
    ws.Range("BV" & FirstRow & ":BV" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "BV")
    ws.Range("BZ" & FirstRow & ":BZ" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "BZ")
    ws.Range("CD" & FirstRow & ":CD" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "CD")
    ws.Range("CH" & FirstRow & ":CH" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "CH")
    ws.Range("CK" & FirstRow & ":CK" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "CK")
    ws.Range("CN" & FirstRow & ":CN" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "CN")
    ws.Range("CQ" & FirstRow & ":CQ" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "CQ")
    ws.Range("CT" & FirstRow & ":CT" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "CT")
    ws.Range("CW" & FirstRow & ":CW" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "CW")
    ws.Range("CZ" & FirstRow & ":CZ" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "CZ")
    ws.Range("DC" & FirstRow & ":DC" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "DC")
    ws.Range("DF" & FirstRow & ":DF" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "DF")
    'Add the formulas (note you need the US-format when using .Formula
    '   or you can use your local format with .FormulaLocal

    wb.Close False 'no save

End Sub
```